# REST API with Default Network Credentials in Visual Webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest, visual-web-part, credentials

I have a Visual WebPart, in which I have used REST API to get the data from different lists of different project sites. Below is the code for that.

```
string searchURLWithParam = "http://mysp2013/_api/search/query?querytext='MyKeyword'&selectproperties='ID%2cTitle%2cPath%2cAssignedTo'";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(searchURLWithParam);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml;type=entry";

NetworkCredential cred = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; //new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
request.Credentials = cred;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

As you can see in above code, if I use `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` in Visual WebPart, it gives me error:

> 500, Internal Server Error.

Instead if I use commented code which is `new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");`, it gives me result, which I don't want to use because this credentials needs to be saved somewhere.

Can I get the data without adding user credentials in the code here? or any other alternative to fetch data with REST API in Visual WebPart?